# Sending values from one submitted of the three existing forms using jQ ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So, I've got three forms on a website, two of which are in modal windows. I need to have ajax send input values (i.e. name, phone, email, radio button - price selection different in each form), but I couldn't get it to work, I don't know how to make sure all submitted form's inputs are sent. Here are the form examples:

```
<form action="POST">
  <input type="text" name="user_name">
  <input type="tel" name="user_phone">
  <input type="email" name="user_email">
  <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
<form action="POST">
  <input type="text" name="user_name">
  <input type="tel" name="user_phone">
  <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
<form action="POST">
  <input type="text" name="user_name">
  <input type="radio" name="user_price"value="2000">
  <input type="radio" name="user_price" selected value="4000">
  <input type="radio" name="user_price"value="1000">
  <input type="email" name="user_email">
  <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

I looked into passing a selected state through jq in the data object, but not every form has radio buttons.

Here's the ajax I've been using:

```
$('form').submit(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./mailer/smart.php",
        data: $(this).serialize()
      }).done(function () {
        $(this).find("#name").val("");
        $(this).find("#email").val("");
        $(this).find("#message").val("");
        $('#thankyou').show(); //вместо #thankyou подставь нозвание блока с модальным окном
        $("form").trigger("reset");
      });
      return false;
    });
```

I'm new to the ajax concept, I've googled a lot, but I just don't seem to get it. I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have separate event handler's to send the submitted form values.

We can use selectors to select each form. Lets say if we have id of 'form-1' for the first form, then you can use `$('#form-1').submit(...)` instead of generic form selector.

Comment: So will it then send info from each form? All of them? I only need to send the one submitted, whichever it is of the three. Sorry if I'm being stupid

Comment: @AlexanderKozyrev Have edited the answer. Let me know if that helps

Comment: So three separate ajax handlers for three forms, right? What about the php mailer? Should I have three mailers, with different amount of variables, and different success messages?

Comment: 1. You can combine selectors inside single event handler if the functionality is common. For ex: '#form1 , #form2'